# Select a Item in Item list android

Tags: java, android

I create a list `Item` by a loop like this:

```
private void addItemToList(ItemRepository lst)
{       
    //Add item to list
    for(Item itm:lst.getItems())
    {
        addItem(itm);
    }
}

private void addItem(Item itm)
{               
    View item =   UtilMPos.getViewFromInflater(R.layout.item,Payment_ListItem.this);
    TextView lblItemName = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.inv_lblitemname);
    TextView lblItemDes = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.inv_lblitemdesc);
    TextView lblPrice = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.inv_lblValueItem);

    //Set value for text view
    lblItemName.setText(itm.getItemName());
    lblItemDes.setText(itm.getItemDes());
    lblPrice.setText(Double.toString(itm.getPrice()));

    //----process component item in here
    llstItem.addView(item);             
}
```

Then display ( I use linearlayout to display list item):

```
------------------------------------------------------
item_name 1                               Price
item_descripton
------------------------------------------------------
item_name 2                              Price
item_descripton
------------------------------------------------------
item_name 3                               Price
item_descripton
------------------------------------------------------
```

When click a row, that row will be selected (bold row or something like that) and I can get all data of that row , ex: click row item_name 1 , I get all data row 1.

Comment: Can you rephrase the last part, I'm a half dead cat, but I cannot make heads or tails of it.

Comment: I edited it,can you understand it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a tag object and put itemName, itemDesc, price fields inside it.
Finally do this:

```
item.setTag(tagObjCreated);
```

And when you click on the item and get back the view in the OnClickListener(), access the tag like this:

```
tagObjRetrieved = itemView.getTag();
```

and get back the itemName, itemDesc, price fields you need.

HTH.

Comment: can you explain more?, so for easy imagination, It look like a list contact on Android (show data is the same) , when I click a contact, I will get all information of that contact

Comment: Each item in the list is a view, right? So, what i am suggesting is that you create a Tag Object (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object), and stuff it into the view. And when you are displaying and clicking on the item in the list, in the onclick of the item or OnItemClick if you are using the adapter (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html), you will get the view back. And the view that you get back, get back the tag and retrieve the data you stuffed into the tag (name, desc, price). HTH

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use SimpleAdapter or something for use with your ListView. There are examples in the sample directory of SDK. Look at it. Don't try to create your own List implementation if that can be avoided.

Comment: Yes, I used ListView for this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know "OnClickListener"?

Sample:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  ...
  View item = ...findViewById(...);
  item.SetOnClickListener(this);
 ....


  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.item_name1:
      // do something
      break;
    case R.id.item_name2:
      // do something
      break;
     }

  }


}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes , I know OnClickListener, but I create list item is dynamic
->I can not set dynamic ID for each view that I add and how about when list item have many many item , we can not switch ... case

Comment: Then why dont you use ListActivity with an custom Adapter? There you would have an "OnItemClicked"-Event.

Comment: Hi , thanks nouseforname, I used customize listview, it work fine , I solved all my problem

Answer (score 0):

I found solution .I used customize listview, it work fine , I solved all my problem.